# Show diff between two merges in GIT

Tags: git

I have the next output of my git log:

```
commit de812cfacf6e38e713068e96e15e50c5 (HEAD -> rc1.11, origin/rc1.11, rc1.10)
Merge: b72b512f7 475d8f391
Author: Pep
Date:   Wed May 4 16:09:29 2022 +0000

Merged in TL-XXX (pull request #713)

A description

Approved-by: Pep



commit 475d8f397d524eb5b7f3ec9252b700e
Author: Pep
Date:   Wed May 4 18:07:17 2022 +0200

A description

commit b72b512f7da4f8e7235690c9c72d689cfd1b6a17 (origin/rc1.10, rc1.9)
```

So I would like to get the commits and the info between both rc version that are a new branch from my develop branch. Is there any way to get this info using git commands? With git log I get all the info of every commits between all my rc branches, but I need the info between only the last two ones.

Thanks

Comment: I’m a little uncertain of what you’re asking. Do you want to see the difference in content, or do you want a list of commits that are ancestors of the newer version but not the older one?

Comment: Just say `git diff <commit1> <commit2>`? What's the issue exactly? Looks like you are asking for `git diff rc1.10 rc1.9` — isn't that exactly what the tags are for, so you can do that kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

> the commits and the info between both rc version that are a new branch from my develop branch

I *think* you're asking for the contents of the branch that was merged by that last commit. If so, it's the **symmetric difference**, as described in `git help log`:

> Another special notation is "..." which is useful for merges. The resulting set of commits is
> the symmetric difference between the two operands. The following two commands are equivalent:

> ```
> $ git log A B --not $(git merge-base --all A B)
> $ git log A...B
> ```

or in your case

```
$ git log rc1.9...rc1.10
```

---

As an aside, it looks weird having release candidate branches, because now origin and your local repo disagree on what commits went into a given RC. I think it's more usual for a release candidate to be a tag, same as for a release.